# issue with multifunction utility program in c.

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

The following  program is supposed to read from the command line( using argv[]) and execute either one of three functions:

right(decides whether or not a triangle is a right triangle based on the side length:  by typing mu -r [sidea] [sideb] [sidec]

findtext:(finds the sequence of a string inside of a given file: (ie,"hello") and lists the line number where it found it.

count: (counts the number of tabs, words and backspaces).

Findtext.c is functioning as it should:

for example if i type ./mu -f [string] [file.txt]

it successfully list the file and the line number in the file in which it was found.

but when I run the same code with the -r(right) option it gives me the following segmentation fault:

Program name: ./mu
3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

where am i going wrong in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "count.h"
//#include "right.h"
//#include "findtext.h"

#define STAND_ALONE 1
void right(int, char **);
void count(int, char **);
void findtext(int, char **);
#ifdef STAND_ALONE 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

      printf("\n");
      printf("Can only use one option(-f, -c, -r) at once. sorry!\n");
      printf("\n");


         printf("Program name: %s\n", argv[0]);

    while ((argc > 1) && (argv[1][0] == '-'))
    {
        switch (argv[1][1])
        {
            case 'f': // findtext.c
                printf("%s\n",&argv[1][2]);
                findtext(argc, argv);
                                break;

            case 'r': // right.c
                printf("%s\n",&argv[1][2]);
                right(argc, argv);
                break;
                        case 'c': // count.c
                printf("%s\n",&argv[1][2]);
                count(argc,argv);
                break;

            default:
                printf("Wrong Argument: %s\n", argv[1]);

        }

        ++argv;
        --argc;
    }
    return (0);
}

#endif

void right(int argc, char *argv[]){
int a;
int b;
int c;
int largest;
int a2;
int b2;
int c2;

/*if(argc != 4){
printf("please enter 3 sides, only \n");
} */

a = atoi(argv[2]);
b = atoi(argv[3]);
c = atoi(argv[4]);
//printf("argv2:%s ",argv[2]);
if((a <= 0 )|| (b <= 0) || (c <= 0))
     printf("Only positive values allowed\n"); exit(0);

a2 = (a*a);
b2 = (b*b);
c2 = (c*c);


if((c > a) && (c > b))
     largest = c;
if((b > a) && (b > c))
     largest = b;
if((a > b) && (a > c))
     largest = a;



if(largest == a){
  printf("HEy hey hey!");
  if((b2 + c2) == a2){ printf("%s %s %s is a right triangle\n",argv[2],argv[3],argv[4]); } 
   else{printf("%s %s %s is not a right triangle\n",argv[3],argv[2],argv[4]);}
 }

if(largest == b){
   printf("HEy");
  if((a2 + c2) == b2){ printf("%s %s %s is a right triangle\n",argv[2],argv[3],argv[4]); } 
   else{printf("%s %s %s is not a right triangle\n",argv[2],argv[3],argv[4]);}

 }

if(largest == c){
  printf("yo");
   if((a2 + b2) == c2){ printf("%s %s %s is a right triangle\n",argv[2],argv[3],argv[4]); } 
   else{printf("%s %s %s is not a right triangle\n",argv[2],argv[3],argv[4]);}

 }




} /* end method right() */



void findtext(int argc, char *argv[]){
FILE *fin;
char buffer[100];
int counter;
char *ptr = buffer;
char *result;

//if(argc != 3) {printf("Usage: %s filename  argc:%d\n", argv[0], argc); exit(1);}
  fin = fopen(argv[3], "r");
  if(!fin) {printf("Unable to open %s\n", argv[2]); exit(1); }

 counter = 0; 
 while (fgets(buffer, 99, fin)){
   counter = counter + 1; 
   if(strstr(ptr,argv[2])){
      printf("%d. %s", counter, ptr);
      printf("\n");

     }

  }
  fclose (fin);


}


void count(int argc,  char **argv){
FILE *fin;

int lcounter = 0;
int count = 0;
char name[100];
char ch;

int word = 0;
int nchar = 0;



fin = fopen(argv[1],"r"); // open file

if(fin==0){

printf("Could not find specified file.\n");
exit(0);
}

while((ch = getc(fin)) != EOF)
{

  nchar++;
  if(ch == '\n')
    lcounter++;
  if(isspace(ch) || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n')
      word++;
}

printf("number of characters: %d\n",nchar);
printf("Lines: %d\n",lcounter);
printf("words: %d\n",word);
printf("\n");

fclose(fin);


}
```

Comment: SO is not a substitute for a debugger.

Comment: Please include the exact error message text. Are you getting a line number where the error is occurring?

Comment: I think GDB is a pretty useful/powerful debugger.

Comment: It just says segmentation fault it doesnt say what line the its coming from.

Comment: " it doesnt say what line the its coming from" -- it will if you use the correct flags and tools.

Comment: @user2467276 Run debugger. You'll see that line then

Comment: The logic of that main loop is rather odd (i.e., wrong). Look into getopt.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((a <= 0 )|| (b <= 0) || (c <= 0))
 printf("Only positive values allowed\n"); exit(0);
```

Beware to the if-block. You are not using braces. At this point of the *right* function the program will end, in any case.

Of course this is not the bug you are looking for but it offers a starting point: the bug must necessarily be before this point.

You may need to debug what goes on here:

```
a = atoi(argv[2]);
b = atoi(argv[3]);
c = atoi(argv[4]);
```

Comment: Domenico, your right. I shoud have added braces in that if statement. However, I wanted the program to exit on the input of negative values.

Comment: with regards to the a = atoi(argv[2]), I set it up to convert from char to int. I even added test print statements in order to make sure a,b,c has values.

Comment: @user2467276 And what do you want to do if less than three sides are entered? (Get a segvio, apparently.)

Answer (score 0):

1. See @Domenico De Felice answer.
2. Add `#include <string.h>`, `#include <ctype.h>`
3. You are accessing `chars` in argv[1] without knowing it is long enough to have those characters. `while ((argc > 1) && (argv[1][0] == '-'))`.  `printf("%s\n",&argv[1][2]);` should print only a line feed as `argv[1]` is "-r".
4. in `right()`, you do `c = atoi(argv[4]);` without knowing 5 args exist.
5. please review the need for your *interesting* code `++argv;` `--argc;`.  I really don't think these are going to do what you may want.

I think you are crashing because you do not always put the numbers of arguments (command parameters) that your code hopes to read.  Increase your validation of program parameters before using them.

5.

Comment: so should I add an if statement checking the value of argc?        like if(argc < 5) {printf("Not enough args");}

Comment: Yes, you need to insure argc is great enough.  (Note: my point #3 might be incorrect.)  Tell me about ++argv; --argc; look like trouble.

Comment: im assuming the user enter ./mu -r 3 4 5  for example argv[0] being mu argv[1] being -r argv[2] being 3 argv[3] being 4 and argv[4] being 5. how else can I access the triangles side lengths.

Comment: Please provide a transcript of a sample run like: `Mark1a\Debug>Mark1a   -r 3 4 5` `Can only use one option(-f, -c, -r) at once. sorry!` `Program name: Mark1a` `yo3 4 5 is a right triangle`  The code works for me.

Comment: Thanks Domenic and Chux, my segmentation fault is gone and compiler warnings are gone. However its not printing whether or not the sides are a right traingle.

Comment: Hope your have the `exit()` correct.  Should you post a question again, recommend better format your code - it wasn't too bad.  But **simplify** the example that contains your problem, rather than presenting _everything_.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You are crashing because you are trying to increment `argv` which is an array variable, not a pointer. So you cannot do argv++;

as a good programming principle, (although it is optional) argc, and argv should NOT be touched; you should use point to them using other variables if you want to run through them.

There are many other uglinesses in the code that try to access pointers and addresses without actually confirming whether they are there.

However, to begin with argv is where you are seg-faulting.